# gitolite package doesn't create user

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, gitolite

I installed gitolite using

```
apt-get install gitolite
```

and according to this [tutorial](http://www.silassewell.com/blog/2011/01/08/setup-gitolite-on-ubuntu/) (and many others) there should be a gitolite user but when i do

```
su - gitolite
```

i get Unknown id: gitolite

Do i need to created it manually? 
I have to add that this is the second time i try to install gitolite, so i first removed it and then reinstalled it. Maybe there is some stuff left that wasn't remove?

Comment: Would be much better asked on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following command and the user will be created:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gitolite
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [Installation Guide for Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/1-INSTALL.mkd), there is no need for a '`gitolite`' user.

> A bare minimum gitolite setup has:
>
> - a server
> - a "**hosting user**" on the server (a real Unix `userid`; we use "`git`" in this document, although RPM/DEB installs use "`gitolite`")
> - a virtual "admin user" -- the user who sets up gitolite and configures it the admin user's client or workstation, from which he does all his work.

You can name your "hosting user" whatever name you want.
You only need a real Unix `userid` user. You can create one manually if you want, or pick an existing one.